# Separating existing web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, git

I have inherited an existing .Net/angularJS project. We have a need moving forward to allow customization per client, while still maintaining synchronization through version control (in this case, git).

I'm not a .Net developer--my .Net experience is limited to writing a service a couple of years ago, starting the BrowserStack tests for the project, and the occasional foray for code review type activities. I'm primarily a Flash/Flex developer with a fair amount of ASP Classic and some PHP experience.

My preliminary research seems to indicate that I can do what I need to do with a git subtree, but I need to find where the seams should be to separate out the custom stuff from the shared code. Right now, the HTML and JS are in the same directory as the web services. My first order of business will be to separate those out, but I don't completely understand

- Why everything's all in one place to begin with
- What the implications are of moving things (project settings, paths, etc.)

When I wrote the service way back, I do remember that we had to scrap the service because the server we had the site on didn't support that version of .Net and it wouldn't work across domains so I could host the service on a server where it would work. I know that things have changed and there's now a way to allow that, but I figure that's the sort of problem I should be looking to avoid as I do this.

I figure I can't be the first person needing to make this kind of separation in a project I think started from the monolithic web project template, but because of a short deadline and a lack of knowledge of .Net, I'd feel better if someone could point me in the right direction or at least alert me to some of the gotchas I should plan to encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept digging, and I finally found a pair of tutorials that address exactly this issue.

- [Creating an empty ASP.Net Project Powered by Angular JS Using Visual Studio](http://www.jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/06/creating-empty-aspnet-project-powered.html)
- [AngularJS Consuming ASP.NET Web API RESTful Services](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/08/angularjs-consuming-aspnet-web-api.html)

In a nutshell, you copy the client's url from the properties panel to the service properties panel and add '/api' to the end of the URL and allow VS to create a virtual directory for you.

Now for my next trick, figuring out how to publish it...

Answer (score 1):

Are you Trying to decouple the Projects. If so than this might be a good help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439688/Creating-ASP-NET-application-with-n-tier-architect

One of my recent project was almost the same that you mentioned above, So I ended up scrapping the old version and Create a brand new Project and Decoupled the related stuffs in the solution.

The best way of understanding stuff is to make sure you seperate the Client Side (Javascript/Htmls/CSS) and Server Side (EF/SP Calls/DTOs etc) by creating different project to the same solution.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that angular is calling the web services with a relative path to api. I think if I understood that better (what other options there are, what the implications of changing that would be), then I could proceed with more confidence.